# Transform and border-right style not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, border, css-transforms

I have been working on creating a border for a capital letter D. To do this I tried to create a transformed circle and used a `border-right`, but on Safari, this will show a border around the entire circle. When the div is not transformed it works fine, but I really want the div to be rotated. How can I fix this?

```css
.circle {
    height: 130px;
    width: 130px;
    background: none;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border-right: 3px solid blue;
    left: 140px;
    top: 134px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg)
}
.letter {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    color: gray;
    left: 95px;
    top: 120px;
    font-size: 200px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="letter">D</div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: If I use border-top-right-radius and border-bottom-right-radius and border-right, I have the correct border. When I transform this div, it shows the border around the entire div. So the problem lies within the rotation. So my question actually is: How can I remove the 'extra' border I do not want?

Comment: I found the answer to my own question. I had to put the circle div inside the letter div! And not use the rotation command!